# Java transport API gives NoNodeAvailableException connecting to an Elasticsearch instance on VirtualBox

Tags: java, elasticsearch, virtualbox

I have a Windows machine which has a Ubuntu machine on VirtualBox and it runs Elasticsearch 2.4. I have mapped ports 9200, 9300 and 5601 via VirtualBox's port mapping and also allowed ports on iptables in my Ubuntu instance.

However, when Java tries to connect I get this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:64) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at eu.adsdaq.elasticsearch.importer.sync.service.OrderHistoryService.sendBulkRequest(OrderHistoryService.java:133) [classes/:na]
    at eu.adsdaq.elasticsearch.importer.sync.service.OrderHistoryService.syncOrderHistory(OrderHistoryService.java:69) [classes/:na]
    at eu.adsdaq.elasticsearch.importer.sync.service.OrderHistoryService.sync(OrderHistoryService.java:45) [classes/:na]
    at eu.adsdaq.elasticsearch.importer.sync.ElasticsearchSyncService.lambda$0(ElasticsearchSyncService.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at eu.adsdaq.elasticsearch.importer.sync.ElasticsearchSyncService$$Lambda$3/910457645.accept(Unknown Source) [classes/:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) [na:1.8.0_45] ...
```

Before this error, I also see something like this,

```
org.elasticsearch.plugins            : [Chimera] modules [], plugins [], sites []
```

That logs happens on the last line of this snippet where I create the Client object initially:

```
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", properties.getClusterName())
            .put("client.transport.sniff", properties.isSniffing())
            .build();
    TransportAddress address;

    try {
        address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(properties.getHost()), properties.getPort());
    } catch (UnknownHostException exception) {
        logger.error("Error : unknown elasticsearch host " + properties.getHost() + ":"
                + properties.getPort(), exception);

        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

    client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(address);
```

So the strange thing is: I don't get the error initially, but I get the error later on when I try to insert data using the same Client.

I used localhost here as my host. When I tried 0.0.0.0 too I get a similar error. I can access http://localhost:9200 from my browser and console. So I know the port mapping works to some degree.

Any help on how I can get resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: If you could show your java code ?

Comment: Have you configured host only adaptor to the vm ? Can you try with that ip address instead of localhost ? Usually host only ip will be something in range 192.168.56.___

Comment: @Kulasangar: Code snippet added :)